# Python type hints - better syntax for cast()?

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting

I recently started using [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) in my code, and have so far found them to be (mostly) very helpful.

However, one thing that I really do not like is the syntax to force the type checker to assume that a variable is of a certain type.  Given this example:

```
import itertools
from typing import Iterable, Tuple
x: Iterable[Tuple[str, str]] = itertools.combinations('abc', 2)
# error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Iterable[Tuple[str, ...]]", variable has type "List[Tuple[str, str]]")
```

As far as I can tell, the recommended way to work around this is to explicitly [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) the object to force the type checker to use the specified type, e.g.:

```
import itertools
from typing import Iterable, Tuple, cast
x = cast(Iterable[Tuple[str, str]], itertools.combinations('abc', 2))
```

I personally find this solution to be a bit gross.  My primary concern is that, to the inexperienced reader, it is not clear that the `cast` is purely there to help the static analyzer.  (If I didn't already know, I would assume based on the name and context that it is converting and doing a copy into an object of the specified type, when really there is no runtime cost.)

`cast` looks like any old function call.  When I see that a function is being called on a value, I expect the value to be mutated and/or some other side-effects to occur, but in this case the only side effect is that `mypy` stops complaining.  Type hints themselves have a distinct syntax, but I feel that this blurs the lines with a mixture of the new typing syntax and traditional python syntax.  (It's already a bit blurry since you have to `import` the types and can compose them, but that's another discussion.)

Is there an alternative syntax for `cast`-like behavior?  I haven't found anything, but I was hoping for something like:

```
x1 = itertools.combinations('abc', 2)) # cast: Iterable[Tuple[str, str]] 

x2: Iterable[Tuple[str, str]] = itertools.combinations('abc', 2)) # type: cast

x3: Cast[Iterable[Tuple[str, str]]] = itertools.combinations('abc', 2))
```

Comment: I do not believe there is any alternative, no. It was probably a compromise solution. You probably should tag this with `mypy`

Comment: Assuming a function will have side effects would be a good habit to break, as it stems from the decades-long practice in the programming language community of abusing the term "function". The name `cast` itself, though, is meant to suggest that it *doesn't* do anything except return the same value. I also doubt *this* is what an inexperienced user will trip over regarding type hinting.

Comment: Are these casts even needed? `mypy` ships with the `typeshed`, which [includes a definition for `itertools.combinations`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/itertools.pyi#L103). It's slightly wrong (it declares it an `Iterable`, not an `Iterator`), but that matches your declaration anyway.

Comment: @chepner: I'm not sure what your point is? The `typeshed` should be declaring all `product`, `permutations` and `combinations` related things as `Iterator`s; it's a mistake that `combinations` and `combinations_with_replacement` are declared as `Iterable`s (`product`/`permutations` are correctly declared as `Iterator`s).

Comment: @ShadowRanger The cast is needed is to set the size of the inner tuple (`Tuple[str, str]` instead of `Tuple[str, ...]`).  Normally the variadic size would make sense since `combinations` can depend on a runtime value, but in my case I always only ever want sequences of length 2.

Comment: I don't know if it's really any less ugly, but you could do `x: Iterable[Tuple[str, str]] = ((a, b) for (a, b) in itertools.combinations('abc', 2))`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the latest version of Mypy does return the correct type `Iterator[Tuple[str, str]]`.

This change was introduced to Typeshed in PR https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/4309.

If you cannot update mypy to the latest version you can checkout the latest version from `typeshed` and use the config option `custom_typeshed_dir`.

See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-custom_typeshed_dir for more details.